# Try to get Index of element in String[] with error handling

Tags: swift

I use `self.stnIdData.index(of: self.itemAtDefaultPositionId)!` to get the index of an element in my String[]. If - for some reason - the element is not in the array, I need to throw an error. 
I tried it with the following piece of code:

```
do {
    var indexOfSelectedId = 0
    try indexOfSelectedId = self.stnIdData.index(of: self.itemAtDefaultPositionId)!

    var counter = 0
    for currStn in self.pickerData {
        if(counter == indexOfSelectedId){
            self.itemAtDefaultPosition = currStn
        }
        counter += 1
    }

    print(" PV: itemAtDefaultPosition: \(self.itemAtDefaultPosition)")
    var defaultRowIndex = self.pickerData.index(of: self.itemAtDefaultPosition!)
    print(" PV: defaultRowIndex: \(defaultRowIndex)")
    if(defaultRowIndex == nil)
    {
        defaultRowIndex = 0
    }
    self.stnPicker.selectRow(defaultRowIndex!, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

} catch let error{
    print("Error while setting ID: \(error)")
}
```

But I get this warning in xCode in this line: `try indexOfSelectedId = self.stnIdData.index(of: self.itemAtDefaultPositionId)!`:

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

Comment: There is no `String[]` in Swift. It's called `[String]`, a.k.a. `Array<String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` can only be used with a method that is declared to `throw`. `index(of:)` is not such a method. Since `index(of:)` returns an optional, just use normal optional unwrapping using `if let`.

```
if let indexOfSelectedId = self.stnIdData.index(of: self.itemAtDefaultPositionId) {
    var counter = 0
    for currStn in self.pickerData {
        if(counter == indexOfSelectedId){
            self.itemAtDefaultPosition = currStn
        }
        counter += 1
    }

    print(" PV: itemAtDefaultPosition: \(self.itemAtDefaultPosition)")
    var defaultRowIndex = self.pickerData.index(of: self.itemAtDefaultPosition!)
    print(" PV: defaultRowIndex: \(defaultRowIndex)")
    if(defaultRowIndex == nil)
    {
        defaultRowIndex = 0
    }
    self.stnPicker.selectRow(defaultRowIndex!, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
} else {
    // Not found - handle as needed.
}
```